# How to correct the "Windows Activation Period has Expired" message on an Esri Amazon AMI?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, amazon-ec2

I'm only getting this error with instances that were spun up with Esri AMIs.  And I did find one post on the AWS forums (with no resolution) regarding this issue.  Does anyone know what the troubleshooting/correction steps are for this issue? <s>I have not started any troubleshooting steps yet.</s>

1. Restarted instance (**No effect**).
2. Checked KMS . (**No KMS Issues**).
3. Turned off firewall, modified C:\Program Files\Amazon\Ec2ConfigService\Settings\config.xml by setting `Ec2WindowsActivate` to `Enabled`.
4. Restarted Ec2Config service.
5. Success!
6. Turned firewall back on. <s>on but I still need to test the KMS...I probably still need to open up a port.</s>
7. Firewall is back on and no issues.

EDIT:
AWS Forum Link: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=119200

[image]

Comment: https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/16822-how-to-activate-windows-after-the-activation-period-expires can solve my problem like the picture above. after i use win7loader by daz :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked for me, but I have a feeling this issue will come back so this answer may change:

1. Turned off firewall, modified C:\Program Files\Amazon\Ec2ConfigService\Settings\config.xml by setting `Ec2WindowsActivate` to `Enabled`.
2. Restarted Ec2Config service.
3. Turned firewall back on.

Answer (score 3):

You could try this:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/Windows-Server-Diagnostics.html

"The AWS Diagnostics for Microsoft Windows Server tool is available free of charge and can be downloaded and installed from https://s3.amazonaws.com/ec2-downloads-windows/AWSDiagnostics/AWSDiagnostics.zip."

"One use case is diagnosing problems with Key Management Service (KMS) activations. KMS activation can fail if you have changed the DNS server, added instances to a domain, or if the server time is out of sync. In this case, instead of trying to examine your configuration settings manually and debugging the issue, run the AWS Diagnostics for Microsoft Windows Server tool to give you all the information you need on possible issues."

Comment: No issues being reported--the KMS Servers are present according to the diagnostics tool.